# Auto-correlation of multivariate time series in R

Tags: r, matrix, time-series

I have a matrix which contains 12 variables, each with 1343 observations. I wish to compute the auto-correlation for each of these variables and use the full length of the data to do so i.e. `lag.max = 1343`.

Using the `acf()` function I can compute the auto-correlation for a single variable but I wish to plot all 12 in a single matrix plot (3 x 4).

Using `acf(linear[,1],lag.max = (length(linear)))` produces:

[image: auto-correlation of a single variable]

My data looks as follows:

```
> class(linear)
[1] "matrix"

> str(linear)
 num [1:1343, 1:12] -102 -101 -101 -101 -101 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:1343] "2017-01-20 16:30:00" "2017-01-20 16:45:00" "2017-01-20 17:00:00" "2017-01-20 17:15:00" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:12] "DO0182U09A3" "DO0182U09B3" "DO0182U09C3" "DO0182U21A1" ...
```

I've tried passing the range of columns in the linear matrix

```
acf(linear[,1:12], lag.max = 1343)
```

but it seems to produce a kind of acf plot but the headings in each plot seem to indicate a correlation plot, see the image below.

From reading the details in `?acf` I see you can pass a multivariate time series which I believe my `linear` object is but yet I get the correlation plot as per below.

Could my problem be that prior to creating `linear` I had an object called `wideRawXTS`.

```
> str(wideRawXTS)
An ‘xts’ object on 2017-01-20 16:30:00/2017-02-03 16:00:00 containing:
  Data: num [1:1343, 1:12] -102 -101 -101 -101 -101 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:12] "DO0182U09A3" "DO0182U09B3" "DO0182U09C3" "DO0182U21A1" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXlt,POSIXt] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```

Since there were missing values in some of the variables I performed a linear interpolation as follows:

```
linear <- apply(wideRawXTS, 2, na.interpolation, option = "linear")
```

Do I need to reconvert the first column of `linear` to an XTS object?

Can anyone provide some guidance as to where I may be going wrong in producing the auto-correlation matrix plot?

```
> head(linear)
                    DO0182U09A3 DO0182U09B3 DO0182U09C3 DO0182U21A1 DO0182U21A2 DO0182U21A3 DO0182U21B1 DO0182U21B2 DO0182U21B3
2017-01-20 16:30:00     -101.50     -103.37     -103.86     -104.78     -104.95     -105.33     -102.50      -99.43     -104.05
2017-01-20 16:45:00     -101.32     -102.75     -104.22     -104.51     -103.94     -105.29     -102.82     -101.99     -103.94
2017-01-20 17:00:00     -101.45     -103.30     -103.93     -104.70     -104.82     -105.13     -103.72     -103.95     -104.25
2017-01-20 17:15:00     -100.91      -95.92      -99.22     -103.83     -104.72     -105.19     -103.57     -101.36     -104.09
2017-01-20 17:30:00     -100.91     -103.04     -104.09     -102.15     -104.91     -105.18     -103.88     -104.09     -103.96
2017-01-20 17:45:00     -100.97     -103.67     -104.12     -105.07     -104.23      -97.48     -103.92     -103.89     -104.01
                    DO0182U21C1 DO0182U21C2 DO0182U21C3
2017-01-20 16:30:00     -104.51     -104.42     -105.17
2017-01-20 16:45:00     -104.74     -104.65     -105.25
2017-01-20 17:00:00     -105.02     -105.04     -105.32
2017-01-20 17:15:00     -103.90     -102.95     -105.16
2017-01-20 17:30:00     -104.75     -105.07     -105.23
2017-01-20 17:45:00     -105.08     -105.14     -104.89
```

[image: odd plot]

Based on feedback from @eipi10 here is the output from their suggestion. My laptop took about 20 mins to compute this but I've no idea what it represents!! All the plots look to be the exact same.

[image]

Comment: Does this do what you're looking for: `par(mfrow=c(3,4)); sapply(linear, acf, lag.max=nrow(linear))`

Comment: @eipi10 thanks for the reply, your comments did indeed produce a matrix plot but I've no idea what it represents! The horizontal scale seems messed up. I don't know how to add pictures to comments but I'll modify the original post with the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`linear` is a matrix. For the code in my first comment to work, `linear` needs to be converted to a data frame or each column needs to be referenced explicitly. The code below takes the latter approach:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,4))

set.seed(2)
linear = matrix(cumsum(rnorm(12*50)), ncol=12)

sapply(1:ncol(linear), function(i) {
  acf(linear[,i], main=paste("Column:", i), lag.max=nrow(linear))
  })
```

[image]

Comment: thank once again, this had worked for me. One thing I can't figure out is how to pass the column name of the new data frame as you loop through each of the columns. I tried `linearDF <- as.data.frame(linear)

sapply(1:ncol(linearDF), function(i) {
  acf(linearDF[,i], main=colnames(linearDF[,i]), lag.max = nrow(linearDF))
})` but for each subplot title I get a list of all the column names rather than the specific column it's looping through on. Any suggestions?

Comment: any idea how I can pass the column names to each of the matrix plots?